# textareaObject.type == "textarea". what is the use of this?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the use of the "Textarea type Property"?

[W3foos says this:](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_type.asp)

> The type property returns which type of form element a text area is.
>
> For a text area object this will always be "textarea".

I'm sorry, what? Why would confirming that a textarea is a `textarea` ever be necessary?

Also, the example doesn't really support what that says. **"The type property returns which type of form element a text area is."** So a `textarea` is **in** a `textarea`.

I apologize in advance if this is something incredibly straightforward that is just going over my head. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe cause you dont know the object type -.- 
You're assuming you do, that's what's wrong

Comment: That makes more sense. Agreed. ^

Comment: And if you still dont understand: that property is for all form elements, not only textareas.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Okay. So `type` works on every kind of hlml element?

Comment: @thomas For all **form** elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the element's type.

Just like `<input>` elements have a [`type` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement), `<textarea>` elements have a `type` property as well. The difference is that it just returns `"textarea"`.

`<input>`, `<button>`, `<select>` and `<fieldset>` also have a `type`.

Comment: The `type` for `<select>` elements can be "select-one" and "select-multiple" :)

Comment: @Ian: Thanks, I never knew that. The spec says the same thing.

Comment: why are you editing? We already told him that all form elements have type

Comment: Yeah me either, but I guess it "makes sense". I never really had the need to use it, so it wasn't common to know, in my opinion

Comment: Thanks! Wish you would have got the six upvotes. This is a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso: I'm wasn't following your comments on the question.

Comment: @Blender Just wondering - did you mean to remove `<select>` from your example list?

Comment: @Ian: Guess I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Blender No problem, I just thought it was funny because were just talking about it (because it **was** in your answer before) :) I'm blanking on other form elements - are there others?

Comment: @Ian: The spec has also has a `<keygen>` and an `<output>` element, but I've never actually seen them used.